# add-teamuser with script doesn't works

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I try to add user with owner role to a team group.

In UPN.UserPrincipalName I have 2 users
And in GroupID just one groupID (both are in string)

```
foreach($user in $UPN.UserPrincipalName)
        {
            Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $user -role owner
        }
```

That's the error I have :

```
Add-TeamUser : Error occurred while executing Add-TeamUser
Code: UnknownError
Message: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
InnerError:
  RequestId: jkdbsferu-sd1-4rt0-45fc-jdsfifsae435
  DateTimeStamp: 2021-06-01T11:45:16
HttpStatusCode: UnknownError
At C:\Tools\Scripts\Semestre1-1.ps1:70 char:13
+             Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $user -role owner
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-TeamUser], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.ErrorHandling.ApiException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Po 
   werShell.Custom.AddTeamUser
```

But I try like, it works  :

```
$GroupID = "jkdbsferu-sd1-4rt0-45fc-jdsfifsae435" 
$user = "user@domain.com"
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $user -role owner
```

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure the `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` succeeds? No credetial needed or anything?

Comment: Can you run other cmdlets from the module ok? Also, what version of module are you running?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the RequestID in the error matches the GroupID, that's odd. Can you query the Team using `Get-Team` and get the GroupID properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found your issue, I've never seen the source of a foreach be the property of an object:

`foreach($user in $UPN) { Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $user.UserPrincipalName -Role Owner }`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue ...

```
do{    
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
        $GroupID = get-team -DisplayName $team.Fullname | Select-Object GroupID
        $GroupID | Out-File -encoding UTF8 'C:\Tools\Scripts\groupID.csv'
        Write-Host $j
        $j++
    }
    until($GroupID)
```

So I'm sure the GroupID is created and synchronized

And I put GroupId.GroupID (to be sure)

`Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID.GroupID -User $owner -role owner`

And it works !

Thanks guys for the help